# How do you bind parameters in the Python pymysql library?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

As described here https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#paramstyle, in MySql it should be possible to bind parameters using the keyword syntax, like this: `email=:email`. This is different from using an unnamed placehoder syntax, like `email=%s`.

But this code doesn't work:

```
import pymysql 
con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password=pw, database=db_name, port=4306)

stmt = "INSERT INTO `test_table` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (:email, :password)"
with con.cursor() as cursor:
    # Create a new record
    cursor.execute(stmt, {'email': "FOO", 'password': "BAR"})
con.commit()
```

Not even adding

```
pymysql.paramstyle = 'named'
```

at the top.

The error is

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':email, password=:password)' at line 1")
```

but unfortunately, I'm not able to find such documentation (This page doesn't document anything.. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

What is the right syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried what is shown --> https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html

Comment: Yes! That works of course. But as you can see, only the case with the unnamed placeholder '%s' is shown: `INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (%s, %s)`.

I don't know if I explained properly in the question, but I'm interested in the case with a Named keyword. Thanks!

Comment: you define query with `:email` - so you have to use `{"email": ...}` instead of `{"name": ...}`

Comment: You are right, that is a typo in the snippet I posted. Edited, thanks. But that is not the point, if I fix that the error is exacltly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html says:

> If args is a list or tuple, `%s` can be used as a placeholder in the query. If args is a dict, `%(name)s` can be used as a placeholder in the query.

Even though the `:name` placeholder format is in the PEP you reference, the pymysql package does not seem to implement that format.

This should work:

```
stmt = "INSERT INTO `test_table` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (%(email)s, %(password)s)"
with con.cursor() as cursor:
    # Create a new record
    cursor.execute(stmt, {'email': "FOO", 'password': "BAR"})
```